# wcftestclient default config

Tags: wcf, configuration, wcftestclient

Where can I set default config options for wcftestclient?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are no default options. Default configuration is generated in the same way svcutil generates configuration when adding service reference. Information trasported in WSDL are used and rest of values is set to default values based on binding / behavior.

If you want to modify and reuse client config for WcfTestClient you can:

- Open WcfTestClient and let it generate config for you
- In Tools > Options unthick Always config when launching services. It will allow you reusing single config for subsequent WcfTestClient executions in the same project but in the same way it will not automatically modify config based on changes made in service configuration.
- Edit client config with SvcConfigEditor and save it. It will saved modified config to your Documents\Test Client Projects directory. The config will be reused if your service will be executed from the same address.

Comment: beautiful answer..have been trying a lot on how to do this.

Comment: Process fully detailed at http://tzonsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/07/changing-wcf-test-client-configuration.html.